# How to decode strings in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, encoding, elisp

I'm writing an Emacs extension and want to fetch some data from the Internet. Using url-retrieve-synchronously and some simple text processing I can get a string like

"\273\313\271\311\267\335 abcd"

The first several characters are encoded in GBK, I'd like to know how to decode them? Many thanks.

Comment: Are these chinese characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`decode-coding-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Explicit-Encoding.html).

Comment: Thanks, I finally find the problem lies in that I use "GBK" as the argument, but it should be 'gbk